# Exclude some documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I just wonder how would I exclude something in MongoDB

**Query :**

```
db.car3.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$Manufacturer",AvgPrice:{$avg:"$Price"}}})
```

**Result :**

```
_id: fiat, Avg price:2780
_id: Skoda, Avg price:2780
_id: BMW, Avg price:5238
```

I just wonder is there any way that I can exclude the average price for Skoda right now I got all the average but I want to only know fiat and BMW

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$match` as first stage to retain documents that match your criteria, which also helps to lessen the no.of docs for further stages :

```
db.car3.aggregate([
    { $match: { Manufacturer: { $in: ['fiat', 'BMW'] } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$Manufacturer", AvgPrice: { $avg: "$Price" } } }
])
```